# Problem with trigger function that populates tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, sql-update

This is for a school project.

I wrote some PostgreSQL code that creates a trigger that updates data into my 'total_revenue_by_category' table when data is entered into my 'detailed_report' table.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_summary_trigger_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM total_revenue_by_category;
    INSERT INTO total_revenue_by_category (name, total_revenue)
    SELECT c.name, SUM(f.rental_rate) AS total_revenue
    FROM category c
    JOIN film_category fc ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
    JOIN film f ON fc.film_id = f.film_id
    GROUP BY c.name;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
```

This is the trigger statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_summary_trigger
AFTER INSERT 
ON detailed_report
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_summary_trigger_function();
```

So it did execute correctly and when I added new data to the 'detailed_table', it does show.

For example, I inserted the following data:

```
INSERT INTO detailed_report (category_id, name, title, rental_rate)
VALUES (17, 'French New Wave', 'The Chinese Girl', 1.99)
```

Then when I queried the "detailed_report" table, the new data is there. However, when I query the "total_revenue_by_category" table, it has two columns, "name" and "total_revenue". These have the correct data EXCEPT the new data that I added above. It must be something in my trigger that's not adding the new data for some reason.

Comment: As far as I can see, there isn't any dependency in the procedure on the contents of `detailed_report`. Are `category`, `film_category`, or `film` views that reference `detailed_report`? Please include database object DDL for all user defined objects referenced in the question. Without those details, it's very difficuly, if not impossible, to offer useful guidance.

Comment: The `DELETE FROM total_revenue_by_category;` would remove all data so there should be no data in `total_revenue_by_category`. Best guess is this a [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) issue and your trigger function is working on another version of the `total_revenue_by_category` table that is earlier in the path.

Comment: This is best solved by writing a view that uses the `SELECT c.name, SUM(f.rental_rate) AS total_revenue ...` query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this short code block which will update the **"total_revenue_by_category"** table without erasing previously stored data in your trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_summary_trigger_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Check if the category already exists in total_revenue_by_category
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM total_revenue_by_category WHERE name = NEW.name) THEN
        -- Update the existing record
        UPDATE total_revenue_by_category
        SET total_revenue = total_revenue + NEW.rental_rate
        WHERE name = NEW.name;
    ELSE
        -- Insert a new record
        INSERT INTO total_revenue_by_category (name, total_revenue)
        VALUES (NEW.name, NEW.rental_rate);
    END IF;
    
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: This did create a new row but both columns are null. I need them to say 'French New Wave' and '1.99' as I have added a whole new category to the database. Shows in the 'detailed report' table but not the 'total_revenue_by_category' table.